# Backtrack Values from Probability

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, finance

I have a question on Digital options pricing :

$$ \text{Payoff} = E[I(X(T) - K)] $$

Where the indicator function takes one if $X(T) > K $ and zero otherwise.

Solving the expected value we can easily get

$$ \text{Payoff} = P(X(T) > K) $$

So I have a dataset of Payoff vs K and I need to predict out of sample payoff for different values of K, how would i go about solving this? How can i backtrack values from a probability to predict?
I believe if I can get the distribution of $X(T)$, I will be able to get the probability $P(X(T) > K')$

P.S. This is not a problem of typical options pricing because I don't have either time to maturity or the volatility.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: your dataset has samples of the form $(p_i,K_i)$, where $p_i=P(X>K_i)$, which means we have samples from complementary CDF, and we want to find $p_j$ corresponding to some different $K_j$ out of the dataset?

Comment: Yes, that is the case

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, we have a *sampled* version of real complementary CDF (or CDF), which is a staircase function with the data we have. Your future queries seek for a reasonably interpolated CDF, assuming that the RV is probably not discrete. Other than fitting a curve within the constraints of a CDF, I think  a reasonable way to do it is converting your CDF to a histogram, learn a density over the data points and convert back to CDF. Depending on the nature of the data, certain assumptions can be made for parametric density estimation, e.g. assuming a mixture of gaussians and solve for GMM, or apply a non-parametric method such as [Kernel Density Estimation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Kernel_density_estimation) to estimate the desired density function. Then, we automatically have a CDF for our $P(X>K')$ queries later.